# natbib's \citet does not work

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am writing a paper using the springer journal LaTeX template. For some references I want to use in-text citation like this:

[image]

but for some reason, when I try this in my document I get the following:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies.  I tried using \citeauthor and \citeyear, but that does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[numbers, sort, comma, square]{natbib}

\begin{document}


bla bla bla \citet{aaronson1998}.



\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibfile} 

\end{document}
```

BiBTeX entry:

```
@article{aaronson1998,
  title={Translation, validation, and norming of the {D}utch language version of the 
{SF}-36 Health Survey in community and chronic disease populations},
  author={Aaronson, Neil K and Muller, Martin and Cohen, Peter DA and Essink-Bot,   
  Marie-Louise and Fekkes, Minne and Sanderman, Robbert and Sprangers, Mirjam AG and
 te Velde, Adrienne and Verrips, Erik},
  journal={Journal of Clinical Epidemiology},
  volume={51},
  pages={1055--1068},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Oxford; New York: Pergamon Press, c1988-}    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with just 1 author first to rule out that there is some error in the author field?

Comment: No I did not, the answer that Harish gave worked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `unsrtnat` instead of `unsrt` in

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[numbers, sort, comma, square]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibfile.bib}
  @article{aaronson1998,
  title={Translation, validation, and norming of the {D}utch language version of the
{SF}-36 Health Survey in community and chronic disease populations},
  author={Aaronson, Neil K and Muller, Martin and Cohen, Peter DA and Essink-Bot,
  Marie-Louise and Fekkes, Minne and Sanderman, Robbert and Sprangers, Mirjam AG and
 te Velde, Adrienne and Verrips, Erik},
  journal={Journal of Clinical Epidemiology},
  volume={51},
  pages={1055--1068},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Oxford; New York: Pergamon Press, c1988-}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


bla bla bla \citet{aaronson1998}.



\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was using \bibliographystyle{naturemag} and it wasn't working. This solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: I have `{\small
\bibliographystyle{ieee}
\bibliography{refs}
}` it doesn't work for citet and only cite works. Do you know what I should do?